# semantic logging - Azure sink query

Tags: semantic-logging

I am using semantic logging application block and using in proc to log entries into azure table storage(SLABLogsTable). But is there a way to query the SLABLogsTable using StorageClient?

Answer (score 1):

The table you use with SLAB is just a regular azure table. You can work with it the same way as with any other azure table. [Here's the official documentation.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/)